# Ruby on Rails - Generating random number that does not exist in database

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, random, model

In my application I have a `Case` model & every case generated by user has a `case_number`.

`case_number` is generated from my `Case` model. Currently Im creating a 3 digit random number from my model after creating a `case`.

```
class Case < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :random_case_number

  private
    def random_case_number
      random_number = Random.rand(999)
      self.update_attributes(case_number: random_number)
    end
end
```

This have caused so some of the cases have the same `case_number`. How can I from my model generate a random number that has not been currently used & if all of the 3 digit numbers are taken, it can move to 4 digits and so on.

Comment: Why use a three random number and (when all three digits are taken) switch to four digits random number? Why use a sequential id or start with a longer random number? Why do you need randomness if guessing a number would be still possible?

Comment: @spickermann Thanks for comment. I can use 4 digits but as said When I used 3 digits, even then some of the cases had same `case_number` so I want to make sure they are uniq. Randomness are needed so because I need the numbers to be random so the cases doesn't go from 1,2, 3, 4 ....

Comment: IMHO making the case number "random" but only 3 or for digits is a strange requirement. Care to give some details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a random number and ensuring that the number doesn't exist in the database I would do something like this:

```
before_create :assign_unique_case_number

validates! :case_number, uniqueness: true

private

CASE_NUMBER_RANGE = (10_000..99_999)

def assign_unique_case_number
  self.case_number = loop do
    number = rand(CASE_NUMBER_RANGE)
    break number unless Case.exists?(case_number: number)
  end
end
```

Please note that the more case there are in the database the longer it might take to find an unused number. Therefore I suggest using greater numbers right from the start. Greater numbers have another advantage: They are harder to guess what might or might not be important in your application.

Furthermore: Rails cannot guarantee that uniqueness in the database. There might be race conditions that lead to duplicates. The only way to avoid that is to add a unique index to the database column in a migration like this:

```
add_index :cases, :case_number, unique: true
```

Comment: Once all case numbers are used up, this will run forever. And as @spickerman explained: this is not efficient, especially when more and more cases are in the DB.
Also: since the case_number is auto-generated the validation does not add value, it just slows things down by issuing another select to ensure the uniqueness (which it can not really ensure) of a number that has been ensured to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that `case_number` has a unique index in the DB.

`rails generate migration add_unique_index_to_case_number`

Edit the generated migration to look somewhat like this:

```
class AddUniqueIndexToCaseNumbers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_index(:cases, :case_number, unique: true)
  end
end
```

(you might need to drop invalid (duplicate) cases before you can add this index)

This ensures that no invalid case numbers can be added to the DB.

Then I'd use a sequential number not a random one. If eventually all numbers from 100 - 999 are used anyway there is not much sense in making it random (and there is not much entropy in 3 digits so it is easy to guess the number).  It is also a bit cumbersome to select a non existing "random" number when inserting.

```
rails generate migration add_sequence_to_case_numbers
```

And again modify the migration:

```
class AddSequenceToCaseNumbers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]

  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE SEQUENCE cases_case_number_seq;
      ALTER TABLE cases ALTER COLUMN case_number SET DEFAULT nextval('cases_case_number_seq');
    SQL
  end
end
```